What does the blue glowing thing behind a Pokemon in your Bag mean?
Sometimes Pokemon have this blue Aura behind them when you press Pokeball > Pokemon.
What does it mean?

In this kind of questions it's better to add a screenshot

The blue background in Pokemon GO marks a recently caught or added Pokemon. It's the game's way of saying you caught a Pokemon in the last 24 hours.
